# Can't find folder after publish app

Tags: c#, console-application

I have C# console application and I have this code there:

```
var rootDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

var img = $@"Content\\{screenName}.png";
Console.WriteLine(Path.Combine(rootDirectory, img));
```

And of course I have Content folder inside solution where I have my images. It retrieves these images when i run debug but after publishing app app is searching that folder

> C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\KRWNP492.QP2\Content\name.png

Take in consider that inside `KRWNP492.QP2` there isn't any folder named `Content`

I can't change folder where to install that app. And error is that:

> System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
>      at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
>      at X.Common.CommonMethods.IsExpectedScreen(Bitmap currentScreen, String screenName)

What can I do?

Comment: So, you want to publish the content as well? Or do you want to embed the images in your file?

Comment: yes I want that folder (and images inside folder as well) to be published in that folder where my application will be installed

Comment: if you right click your images and select Properties you should be able to set the content type and also if they should be copied to your output directory or not. Not sure if that affects the publishing though. Maybe you already have that set?

Comment: I did that too but my problem is that app is searching that `Content` folder where it isn't (inside appdata..)

Comment: @mm8 no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Solution" directory once the application has been compiled. There is an executable (.exe) and some image files.

What you should do is to set the Build Action property of the image file(s) to "Content" and the Copy To Output Directory property to "Copy if newer" in the properties pane in Visual Studio. This should make sure that the Content directory and the images are copied to the output directory when you build the application.

You could then use a *relative* path to find your images at runtime:

```
string path = $"Content\\{screenName}.png";
System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path);
```

Make sure that you copy the Content folder that contains the images to the deployment directory along with the .exe.

Comment: can't I do that on publish visual studio automatically copy that folder in the deployment directory?

Comment: It depends on how you deploy but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;` to retrieve the path of your application.

Comment: when I write that current folder in debug is `solution/bin/debug/appname.exe` and using my method is solution folder where I have that `content` folder

Comment: The question is not about the application location. It's about why the content isn't where the OP expects it to be. Read the question again more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the StartupPath property to get the directory easily.

```
var rootDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
```

Comment: StartupPath on debug is bin/debug folder and I have that folder inside solution folder..

Comment: The question is not about the startup path. It's about why the content isn't where the OP expects it to be. Read the question again more carefully.